# MySQL taking advantage of primary key

Tags: mysql

I have a database with a table. The table has many rows with columns: (id1, id2, user, ip, time, location). None of the columns are unique. Only the combination of id1 and id2 is.

I have a primary key of the columns id1 and id2 using the command:

```
ALTER TABLE Main ADD PRIMARY KEY (id1, id2)
```

Now, if i search using this query:

```
SELECT user FROM Main WHERE id1 = 'ABFHJK' LIMIT 3
```

Am I taking advantage of the primary key index?

Comment: What you mean by _ advantage !!_

Comment: I mean speed up the query using something like binary search instead of linear search

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski, MySQL can benefit from partial lookups in an index. You don't have to do a lookup for all columns of an index to get its benefit, just a left-most subset of columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add an index on two columns, they work in the order that you've specified them. A primary index on id1 and id2 would make the following queries use the index:

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE id1 = 'foo'
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE id1 = 'foo' AND id2 = 'bar'
```

However, it will not index `id2` alone:

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE id2 = 'bar'
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as described in [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/multiple-column-indexes.html) MySQL will use the index in that case because you are selecting based on the leftmost prefix of the index.

If you were selecting based on `id2` then MySQL would not use the index.